# hibernate not saving data after using commit

Tags: java, hibernate

Data is ot getting saved in my database after writting this also,

```
public saveUser(user){
Session session=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();          //SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                //Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
                Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(user);
                t.commit();
                session.close();
                return 1;
}
```

And i am not getting any exception or error.

Answer (score -1):

Flush the session to push the changes to Database, before closing the session.

Refer below snippet:

```
public saveUser(user){
Session session=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();          //SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(user);
                t.commit();
                session.flush();
                session.close();
                return 1;
}
```